# Saving multiple areas of an image into .JPG files from pixel coordinate data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, image-processing

I have a script here that takes the pixel coordinate data to draw rectangles around features within an image, often drawing multiple features within each image.

My entire script is:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

%matplotlib inline

import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

import glob
import re
```

Creating a dataframe with the relevant values (filename and x/y/r pixel coords of the feature):

```
FandC = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
   filename = row['filename']
   xyrcoords = row['points']
   x, y, r = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',xyrcoords)
   print(f'DEBUG: filename={filename}, x={x}, y={y}, r={r}')
   FandC.append({'filename': filename, 'x':x, 'y':y, 'r':r})

master_df = pd.DataFrame(FandC)
    #creates a dataframe for "filename", "x", "y", and "r".
master_df.sort_values('filename', inplace = True, axis = 0)

master_df['filename'] [master_df['filename']=='M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg']
    # shows "master_df['filename']" where the "filename" is equal to (==) the string "M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg"
```

Creating a function that draws rectangles around the features:

```
def draw_rectangle(filename, master_df):
    img_path = 'G:\\Documents\\Thesis\\AutoSub_Images\\Compiled_transects\\{}'.format(filename)  
    im= Image.open(img_path)
    img1_df = master_df[master_df['filename'].str.match(filename)]
    im = im.convert('RGBA')
    overlay = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)
    
    for index, row in img1_df.iterrows():
        for i in range(len(img1_df)):
            draw.rectangle(((float(row['x'])-float(row['r']), float(row['y'])-float(row['r'])), (float(row['x'])+float(row['r']), float(row['y'])+float(row['r']))), fill=(255,0,0,55))
            #return coords
            
    img = Image.alpha_composite(im, overlay)
    img = img.convert("RGB")

    img.save('G:\\Documents\\Thesis\\Outputs\\Outputs_JPGs\\annotated_{}'.format(filename))
```

Creating a function that saves the new data to .csv file:

```
def write_csv(filename, master_df):
    csv_file = 'G:\\Documents\\Thesis\\Outputs\\Outputs_CSVs\\{}.csv'.format(filename[0:-4])
    img1_df = master_df[master_df['filename'].str.match(filename)]
    
    with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Filename', 'Centerpoint x', 'Centerpoint y', 'Height', 'Width'])
        for index, row in img1_df.iterrows():
            writer.writerow([row['filename'], float(row['x']), float(row['y']), float(row['r'])+float(row['r']), float(row['r'])+float(row['r'])])
```

Executing both functions above:

```
for i, row in master_df.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        filename_tmp = row['filename']
        draw_rectangle(filename_tmp, master_df)
        write_csv(filename_tmp, master_df)
        
    #print(row['filename'] == filename_tmp)  
    
    if row['filename'] == filename_tmp:
        pass
    
    #elif row['filename'] != filename_tmp:
    else:
        #load this img, and plot xenos on top.
        filename_tmp = row['filename']
        draw_rectangle(filename_tmp, master_df)
        write_csv(filename_tmp, master_df)       
            
            
    if i == 50000:      
        break
```

The 'draw_rectangle' function above works well, and produces an image with all the features specified in the coordinate data highlighted by a red box, as seen here:
[image: example_image]

How can I modify this code (or specifically the draw rectangle function), so that instead of exporting the image above with 12 features highlighted on it, I actually export the 12 individual features as seperate image files?

If any clarification is needed, please feel free to ask :)

cheers,
R

Answer (score 0):

After the line `draw.rectangle()` add some new code that does:

```
ROI = im.crop(YOUR BOUNDING BOX)
ROI.save(f'Crop-{i}.png', ROI)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @Mark. I have been trying to implement this with no success. How do I reference 'YOUR BOUNDING BOX' in your 1st line? Could it be easier to write an entirely new function to do this to include in with the other two in the final execution?

Comment: The bounding box is the same as where you draw the red overlay.